# sign up form doesn't work (CSRF token missing or incorrect.) django

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms

I'm trying to do a registration form where users get added to users group in the admin interface but for some reason, the registration form doesn't get saved in the database instead it gives me this error
**Forbidden (403)
CSRF verification failed. Request aborted. Reason given for failure:
CSRF token missing or incorrect.**
can someone tell me what I'm missing here?

**decorators.py**

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import redirect

def unauthenticated_user(view_func):
  def wrapper_func(request, *args, **kwargs):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
      return redirect('index')
    else:
      return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  return wrapper_func

def allowed_users(allowed_roles=[]):
    def decorator(view_func):
        def wrapper_func(request, *args, **kwargs):

            group = None
            if request.user.groups.exists():
                group = request.user.groups.all()[0].name

            if group in allowed_roles:
                return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
            else:
                return HttpResponse('You are not authorized to view this page')
        return wrapper_func
    return decorator

def admin_only(view_func):
    def wrapper_function(request, *args, **kwargs):
        group = None
        if request.user.groups.exists():
            group = request.user.groups.all()[0].name

        if group == 'user':
            return redirect('home')

        if group == 'admin':
            return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

    return wrapper_function
```

**views.py**

```
@unauthenticated_user   
def sign_up(request):

    data = CreateUserForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = CreateUserForm(request.POST or None)
        if data.is_valid():
            user = data.save()
            username = data.cleaned_data.get('username')
            group = Group.objects.get(name='user')
            user.groups.add(group)

            messages.success(request, 'Account was created for ' + username)

            return redirect('login')
        

    context = {'info':data,}
    return render(request, 'signup.html', context)

@unauthenticated_user
def login_page(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password =request.POST.get('password')

        user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)

        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('index')
        else:
            messages.info(request, 'Username OR password is incorrect')

    context = {}
    return render(request, 'signin.html', context)
```

Comment: I've had this problem with Flask when my front end was sending data to the back end to be persisted. Since my backend was using a separate load balancer, the request looked like it was cross sites. I fixed it by adding using a CORS config when starting my backend app. If this scenario is similar to yours, check out the CORS options for Django.

Comment: @G.J I never heard of it. I will look it up thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Just add

> {% csrf_token %}

in your signup.html, login.html...

for example:

```
  <form method="post">
   {% csrf_token %}
   // form here
  </form>
```